# How can I reduce RAM usage of Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am looking for an answer for my Logstash RAM problem because it is nearly 100%. I made a lot of searches for it but they didn't work out for me. Below code is my logstash.conf file. I think it needs small touches.

Logstash.conf:

```
input {
  file {
        path => ["c:/mylogs/*.txt"]
        start_position => "beginning" 
        discover_interval => 10
        stat_interval => 10
        sincedb_write_interval => 10
        close_older => 10
        codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  date {
        match => ["mydate","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS" ]
        timezone => "UTC"  
  }
  date {
        match => ["TimeStamp", "ISO8601"]
  }

  json {
        source => "request"
        target => "parsedJson"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "http://localhost:9200" ]
        index => "log-%{+YYYY.MM}"
  }
}
```

Comment: See also: https://marschall.github.io/2016/08/16/setting-logstash-jvm-options.html

Answer (score 2):

Logstash uses a JVM to run. JVM options used by logstash can be configured in the jvm.options file, in the config folder of your logstash folder ([see the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.6/config-setting-files.html)). In the file you can set a `-Xmx` option to set the max heap size, which would limit the max memory used.

From the tuning logstash [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.6/tuning-logstash.html), you can also configure the batch size and number of worker to reduce the number of in-flight events, which should reduce the RAM usage, but also reduce the throughput of logstash.